# While installing any package npm throw a require stack error with code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, error-handling

While i try to install anything from npm install command it will trow an error, "require stack" and "code MODULE_NOT_FOUND"

```
C:\Users\dell>npm audit fix
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
←[90m    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)←[39m
    at createEnginesValidation ←[90m(C:\Users\dell\←[39mAppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\cli.js:7:15←[90m)←[39m
    at module.exports ←[90m(C:\Users\dell\←[39mAppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\cli.js:78:27←[90m)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> ←[90m(C:\Users\dell\←[39mAppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\bin\npm-cli.js:2:25←[90m)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

if someone has answer so please let me know.

if someone has answer so please let me know.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run `fix` in a folder without a `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

The `npm audit fix` command is used to fix vulnerabilities in the dependencies of a project.

You are also getting: `Error: Cannot find module ../package.json`.

In order to start a project (and also install dependencies), you will need a `package.json` file in your project directory. If you do not have one, you can automatically create one by running the `npm init` command, which will initialize a new project in the current directory.
Then, you can start installing dependencies to your project by `npm install <dependency_name>`.